# Does Pandas ExcelWriter work with excel 365, or which version of excel it supports

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

same code for excelwriter working with excel 2013, but not excel365. what version of excel pandas excelwriter supports?

have code as below:

tested workign with excel 2013, but not excel 365, could not find the excek version support for pandas.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fname1, engine='xlsxwriter')
```

Comment: what doesn't work? are you getting an error message? is no file generated?

Comment: no file generated, thank you

Answer (score 1):

it turned out not the excel version problem, but a problem that can not write to external flash driver